# Why does wc <<<"$string" show a one-byte-longer length than printf "$string" | wc?

Tags: bash, newlines, wc, here-string

Accidentially, I found out that `wc` counts differently depending on how it gets the input from bash:

```
$ s='hello'
$ wc -m <<<"$s"
6
$ wc -c <<<"$s"
6
$ printf '%s' "$s" | wc -m
5
$ printf '%s' "$s" | wc -c
5
```

Is this - IMHO confusing - behaviour documented somewhere? What does `wc` count here - is this an assumed newline?

Comment: You can always pipe to `od -c` to see exactly what you have.

Comment: Or, better, `xxd -g1`.

Comment: I hope `printf "$s"` isn't your actual script... hopefully you meant `printf "%s" "$s"`

Comment: Since there were so many comments about printf, I edited my post to reflect best practice.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The difference is caused by a newline added to the here string. See [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings):

> The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline appended, to the command on its standard input (or file descriptor *n* if *n* is specified).

`wc` is counting in the same way, but its input is different.

Comment: If should be noted that to print the (arbitrary) content of a variable without an added newline character, it should be `printf %s "$var"` (or `print -rn -- "$var"` with ksh-like shells), not `printf "$var"` which wouldn't work correctly for values of `$var` that contain `%` or backslash characters (or start with `-` with most implementations).

Comment: Note that the original here-string implementation in the Unix port of `rc` did not add that newline character.

Answer (score 26):

It's a succeeding newline added by the here-string redirector:

```
$ s="hello"
$ hexdump -C <<<"$s"
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a                                 |hello.|
00000006
$ printf "$s" | hexdump -C
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f                                    |hello|
00000005
```